# Java ME SDK 3.2 MQTT Client

Tags: java-me, mqtt, paho

I'm looking for MQTT Client library for Java ME 3.2 SDK. I found Paho Java ME client for MQTT but it cannot be compiled. Do you know any library for connect to mqtt broker?

Comment: Software suggestions/recommendations are off topic for Stack overflow, but if you update the question with details of the compiler failure somebody may be able to help

Answer (score 0):

As hardillb said, it is a bit off target, but if you really need and MQTT library for Java you have Paho, or [mqtt-client](https://github.com/fusesource/mqtt-client) written by Hiram Chirino, which are for me, the best ones.